# Storage.sync.set() to save the extension state

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

Im making a Chrome Extension! im kinda new to this and im still trying to figure out how to store the extension state even if the popup is reload or user leaves the page or closes the browser..
i have used the storage.sync.set() function... i was thinking to use local storage for this.. can you please tell me how can i?
getExtensionState function states the bool value of state sends it to content.js

Popup.js

```
let extensionState = false;

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function () {
  extensionState = !extensionState;
  if (extensionState) {
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Disable";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Enable";
  }
  getExtensionState();
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ state: extensionState }, function () {
    console.log(extensionState);
  });
});

function getExtensionState() {
  (async () => {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true,
      lastFocusedWindow: true,
    });
    const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
      state: extensionState,
    });
    // do something with response here, not outside the function
    console.log(response);
  })();
}
```

Popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/popup.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Popup</h1>
    <button id="toggle"></button>
  </body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use chrome.storage.sync.get at the beginning of the script and change innerHTML accordingly.